# Embedding SVG in PDF (exporting SVG to PDF using JS)

Tags: javascript, pdf, svg, pdf-generation

The starting points: I don't have a server that can provide anything but static files. And I have an SVG element (dynamically created) in my `<body>` that I want to export to a vector format, preferrably PDF or SVG.

I started looking at using the already existing lib [jsPDF](http://code.google.com/p/jspdf/) along with [downloadify](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/wiki/jspdf-using-downloadify). It worked fine. Unfortunately, this does not support SVG, only text.

I've read about the PDF format's possiblities to embed SVG images, and [it seems](http://www.kevlindev.com/utilities/index.htm) to have been enabled since Acrobat Reader 5 (along with the ImageViewer plugin). But it doesn't work. I've tried with 3 different PDF readers without success.

Does this mean that PDFs has dropped SVG embedding support? I haven't found anything on this.

I have two questions; can this be solved? And if yes, what are the specifications for embedding SVG inside of a PDF? With that info, I can build that support in jsPDF myself.

The browser support demands are Safari, Chrome and Firefox. The versions that supports SVG.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

For anyone looking for a JS-only solution: **[PDFKit](http://pdfkit.org/)** seems to be the superior solution to generate PDF from JS these days, and it supports all SVG geometry primitives (including interpreting `path` geometry strings) out of the box. All that would be needed to render existing SVG content would be a DOM-walker that keeps track of CSS styling and inheritance, if you do not require complex stuff like symbols etc.

I wasn't successful with the sketchy SVG support of the **jsPDF**/**svgToPdf** combo mentioned in the other answer, and the source code of these two didn't look very well-crafted and complete to me.

Edit: Usage example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/klesun/zg4qbwd8/42/)

Comment: One question. 
1. Open http://pdfkit.org/demo/browser.html.
2. Open Chrome Inspect Window.
3. Click "Toggle Device Toolbar" icon  on the top menu.
4. Refresh the page.
5. I CANNOT see the pdf on the right window in the mobile view.
6. Do anyone know why the mobile view is not rendering the PDF. ? Is it this PDFKit specific or general problem with opening pdf on mobile ?

Comment: PDFKit in conjunction with https://github.com/alafr/SVG-to-PDFKit seems to be the way to go.

Comment: cant convert html to pdf directly

Comment: It doesn't support the image tag!?

Answer (score 7):

I'll reply to my own question. I ended up using [DocRaptor](https://docraptor.com/examples#jquery_example) that can be called client-side from JavaScript. This technically solves my problem, even though it is a non-free solution. If I the answer could be a server-side-solution, I could use [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) as [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913338/embedding-svg-in-pdf-exporting-svg-to-pdf-using-js/5913944#5913944) by Mic.

Comment: Thanks for the link to DocRaptor. If you go the route of hosting something, you can use WKHTMLTOPDF, as it is free and open sourced

Comment: Added your answer and removed Prince XML as an alternative, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

**jsPDF** has a plugin for that: **svgToPdf**:

https://github.com/ahwolf/jsPDF/blob/master/jspdf.plugin.svgToPdf.js

I haven't tried it, but this could allow discarding the use of an external API and/or having to rely on a server-side solution.

Comment: I'm currently trying this approach but I only seem to get a blank pdf from it. Do you know of any examples out there that use this plugin?

Answer (score 4):

Did you try WKHTMLTOPDF? It's a free tool based on webkit.
We wrote a small tutorial [here.](http://beebole.com/en/blog/general/convert-html-to-pdf-with-full-css-support-an-opensource-alternative-based-on-webkit/)

On a Mac, with Safari or Chrome, you can save an HTML page with embedded SVG to a PDF.
Since these browsers use WKHTMLTOPDF internally, may be this will work for you as well.

Comment: I'm asking for a client-side solution here. However, you are right in that I've not specified what browser support I'm going for. So I've now edited my answer to include that

Comment: I, unfortunately, still can't make wkhtmltopdf work. It only produces blank pages for me.

Comment: @art-solopov, times have changed, as mentionned above, you could switch to pdfkit: http://pdfkit.org/docs/vector.html

Answer (score 1):

Minimal example using `pdfkit`, `svg-to-pdfkit` and `blob-stream`, that downloads an SVG DOM element as a PDF.

1. Import packages in your `index.html`.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfkit@0.10.0/js/pdfkit.standalone.js"></script>
<script src="https://bundle.run/blob-stream@0.1.3"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/svg-to-pdfkit@0.1.8/source.js"></script>
```

2. Run this function, where `svg` is an SVG DOM element, or SVG string.

```
function downloadPDF(svg, outFileName) {
    let doc = new PDFDocument({compress: false});
    SVGtoPDF(doc, svg, 0, 0);
    let stream = doc.pipe(blobStream());
    stream.on('finish', () => {
      let blob = stream.toBlob('application/pdf');
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link.download = outFileName + ".pdf";
      link.click();
    });
    doc.end();
}
```

Comment: shapes are correct but all color and text is blacked out.

Comment: @Frank hmmm.. can't reproduce. What browser and version? Anyone else getting this?

Comment: I created a minimal example here and linked to your answer in the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72061301/strange-output-when-converting-svg-to-pdf-javascript-mermaid-js-example

Comment: Thanks! it works as I needed except cyrillic symbols from svg is not shown on pdf. Do you have any clue how to get them shown?

Answer (score -1):

EVO HTML to PDF Converter has support for converting the SVG embedded in HTML to PDF. You can see an example for this feature here : http://www.evopdf.com/demo/HTML_to_PDF/HTML5_Features/SVG_to_PDF.aspx . The sample code for this is:

```
// Create a HTML to PDF converter object with default settings
HtmlToPdfConverter htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter();

// Convert the HTML page with SVG to a PDF document in a memory buffer
byte[] outPdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertUrl(urlHtmlWithSVG);

// Send the PDF as response to browser

// Set response content type
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");

// Instruct the browser to open the PDF file as an attachment or inline
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename=SVG_to_PDF.pdf; size={0}", outPdfBuffer.Length.ToString()));

// Write the PDF document buffer to HTTP response
Response.BinaryWrite(outPdfBuffer);

// End the HTTP response and stop the current page processing
Response.End();
```

Comment: EVO pdf doesn't fit the svg image on entire pdf page. There is lot of blank space on all the sides of the image. I have tried all the option like FitWidth, FitHeight, StretchToFit etc. But couldn't solve the issue.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue as ArpitGupta where the layout around the SVG is completely wrong when using @EvoPdf I have a container div wrapping an SVG and I'm using flexbox to vertically & horizontally center the container. When converted to PDF, the layout/alignment is the same as if I completely remove the flexbox styles.