# Download Raphael canvas as a SVG or PDF

Tags: svg, raphael

I am using Raphael to create a dynamic visualization. Is it possible to allow the image generated on the Canvas to be downloaded as a SVG/PDF or another image format?

Comment: In response to the first comment. I am targeting all standards-compliant browsers. Would prefer a free solution ideally and no Flash. Server-side solutions are fine.

Comment: The first answer supplies you with a solution for what you are asking: Use Vector Converter to get VML as SVG (this step is just for IE6-8). Then use wkhtmltopdf to process the SVG into a PDF document. Return it as application/pdf and voilá!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are pieces of information missing here, namely browser support, server-/client-side solution and whether costs are okay or not. So I'll try to give you an exhaustive answer.

For a client-side solution, you can use [DocRaptor](https://docraptor.com/examples#jquery_example). Just feed the SVG tree to DocRaptor This works for the SVG-producing browsers (all since 2005 except for IE prior to version 9). Note that DocRaptor has a fee for converting documents into PDF. For a free server-side solution for converting an SVG tree to a PDF, I would suggest using [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) as proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913338/embedding-svg-in-pdf-exporting-svg-to-pdf-using-js).

For IE6-8, which Raphaël produces VML for, you could create a PHP solution using the [Vector Converter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vectorconverter/) library. When the conversion from VML to SVG is finished, sent the SVG to DocRaptor (or wkhtmltopdf).

There is no free client-side VML/SVG -> PDF solution that works for VML or SVG. To build that would mean interpreting SVG and/or VML, creating a PDF from it using JavaScript (there are JS PDF [library](http://code.google.com/p/jspdf/) [attempts](https://github.com/marak/pdf.js/)), and sending it to the client using [some Flash technique](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify). I guess nobody has attempted to build that yet. I might.

Comment: [jspdf](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) will create a pdf from html or through its own library library calls. BTW pdfjs is depreciated, shame because it was quite good!

Answer (score 5):

[pdfkit](http://pdfkit.org/) seems to be the way to go, with using browserify to make the node code run client side. There is a nice demo [here](http://pdfkit.org/demo/browser.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can save as an image using **canvg** and **canvas2image** libraries

- http://code.google.com/p/canvg/
- http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/