# Generate PDF from SVG/paper js

Tags: javascript, pdf, svg, paperjs

I'm using [paper.js](http://paperjs.org/) to generate SVG-files in the browser.

**Is there a way to generate PDF's from these SVG's?**

I have javascript and .NET in my toolbox and using third party components for generating the PDF documents is not a problem. I'm currently looking at [SelectPDF](http://selectpdf.com/community-edition/) as a possible candidate for generating the PDF's. It works great with HTML but I'm not sure it handles SVG's that well.

Comment: Just found this, might be worth taking a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16396580/4543256

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf

Down the left side navigation there are many samples of SVG to PDF charts. The one item to check is if your implementation code inserts the appropriate SVG namespace. Some of the samples show doing so if the charting library doesn't.

API guide is here http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.APIDoc.Usage and shows both formatting div with content or even just specific SVG.