# Download SVG with image and patterns as PDF

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a SVG with image and patterns applied on rects, how to download the whole thing as a PDF using javascript?

here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/dnuboz21/5/

```
<div class="feature">
<svg style="height: 100%;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100%;">
    <image width="980" height="600" xlink:href="http://en.hdyo.org/assets/art-shutter-young-people-a12e2c0cd7a54920cb024fd1394190fd.jpg" clip-path="url(#svg-mask)" />
    <defs>
        <pattern width="1" height="1" id="pat1" viewBox="325 110 150 150" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
            <image width="980" height="652" xlink:href="http://en.hdyo.org/assets/art-shutter-young-people-a12e2c0cd7a54920cb024fd1394190fd.jpg" style="filter:url(#svg-blur);" />
        </pattern>
        <filter id="svg-blur">
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10" />
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <rect x="325" y="110" rx="40" ry="40" width="150" height="150" style="fill:url('#pat1');stroke:red;stroke-width:5;" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't just download it as PDF. To create PDF you need a PDF tool like:

- http://d3export.housegordon.org/
- https://parall.ax/products/jspdf
- http://www.wikihow.com/Create-PDF-Files
- [Embedding SVG in PDF (exporting SVG to PDF using JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913338/embedding-svg-in-pdf-exporting-svg-to-pdf-using-js)

For more, search for example Google [create pdf with browser](https://www.google.no/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=create%20pdf%20with%20browser)

Another option would be to just print it. Many of today's browser has the option to print to PDF.

- [Print directly from browser without print popup window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096862/print-directly-from-browser-without-print-popup-window)
- https://superuser.com/questions/161313/print-a-huge-svg